# Windows server2012 not able to ping or access website outside network

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ping

I am using Windows server 2012 to host website. Everything was working fine from few years, but from past two days, I am not able to ping or access website hosted in this server. I am not sure what details to attach.

In server manager window, logs looks this,unable to start WinRM, http, UPnp services

[image]

I have tried below approach, none of them are working

1- Ping command **NOT** working from outside network for public IP and domain address.

2- Ping command works inside same network/machine for public IP and domain.

3- I have refreshed DNS, Not working

4- Added ICMP rule in Firewall--Not working.

5- Disabled All Firewall--Not working

Please let me know where I am going wrong. is it a Firewall issue or something else.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you did not correctly add the rule to the Firewall.

Windows firewall has separate interpretations for what it considers your internal network (the subnet you are on) and everything else is considered public network and a different set of rules applies.

To make sure this part is fine you can try doing it from a command line:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMPv4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

What else can you test:

- Completely turn off the Firewall temporary, just for a quick test to see if there is any difference. Also make sure no other security applications can interfere with Firewall-related functionality.
- Check what updates installed at the date when the problem started; an update may have broken something. If you identify updates made at the date when the problem started, remove them.
- If you have another available public IP, try changing to it just for testing.

Comment: Did not work, I have tried command you have given to me! But unable to ping to server
-------------------------
C:\Windows\system32>netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMPv4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
Ok.
----------

Comment: One more thing, am able to connect through team viewer, but remote desktop does not works. any idea why it works for team viewer but not for remote desktop

Comment: TW connects to a target server and then practically the whole client-server system starts to work. RDP needs open ports to work. If you have another network device like Router or Firewall you will need to open the needed ports there.

Comment: There is no other router, I think problem with DNS or DHCP. Not able to find

Comment: A DNS problem would not prevent anything to work directly by using the IP. What gives your DHCP in your network ? This also seems unrelated.

Comment: sounds good. So what steps should I try now to resolve this. any hint please, locally I can access website an ping. Outside network why it is not working

Comment: I have added some things you can try in the main answer.

Comment: I have disabled completely firewall, it did not work. there was no software update in server from past 2 month. None of them worked. But I have noticed is "NET stop http" "NET start http" does not works at all. is there any problem with http service?

Comment: Also when I ran network trouble shooter I got message by saying "Default Gate way not available" Not sure for what purpose this error about?

Comment: Sounds like your gateway is no longer configured. What output does an ipconfig /all command shows ? Without default GW, packets won't travel correctly to the outside network.

Comment: I think it is not problem with default gateway, when I looked at server manager logs I found below error "Failed to schedule Software Protection service for re-start at 2119-06-08T10:25:59Z. Error Code: 0x80041316."

Comment: Also when i try to start UpNp service "the Function Discovery Provider Host service depends on the HTTP Service service which failed to start because of the following error" I think HTTP service is not running. How can I find HTTP service is running? or Do I need to re-install?

Comment: I have screenshot server manager in my question, please have look at it.it looks in server manager many service are not running

Comment: Have any services been uninstalled like Web Server, IIS Services, Management tools or Web Publishing Services ? You should also run a SFC scan.

Comment: I have ran sfc /scannow command, and result showed me following message "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations." I think no files are corrupted. Not sure why I am not able to start http service or winrm s